# How do I debug a CUDA library with only 1 graphics card running X11

Tags: debugging, gdb, cuda

I'm running a CUDA library that I need to debug for memory problems and other issues. But when I attach cuda-gdb to the process I get the error

> error: All CUDA devices are used for X11 and cannot be used while debugging.

I understand the error, but there has to be a way that I can debug the issues.  Since I only have 1 GPU, it really isn't practical to turn off X11.

On non Nvidia hardware I thought there was a way to emulate a cuda gpu.  could this be setup for debugging even though I have an NVIDIA gpu?

Comment: @Halpo What's your GPU model?

Comment: Have you tried to debug with emulation mode turned on? (on your NVIDIA GPU)

Comment: Yes I compile with --device-emulation. Load the library attach with cuda-gdb -tui -pid=12148

Comment: Then I get it seems to close the program and gives the error

Comment: Depending on the CUDA version you are using, device emulation may not be available, as it has been deprecated and possibly removed.  Is it feasible to get another GPU (a cheap one for display maybe)?

Comment: I am using the latest 3.2 version.  The problem is that I need at least architecture 1.3, but probably that will change to 2.0 for some things. The fermi cards aren't all that cheep.  I'll just have to work around it for now and then prove that It is worthwhile to get a tesla card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, as you are using Linux you're in a lucky position as you can kill X pretty easily just for the time of debugging.

However, if you really want to stick to running X while debugging you are out of luck, as this is *not* possible for a very good reason: the display driver has a protection mechanism called watchdog timer which is enabled when the GPU in use also drives a display. The watchdog timer interrupts any kernel that runs for longer AFAIR 5s. This is intended to prevent GPU lockups.

Alternatively, you could try using [ocelot](http://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/), but I am not sure how good are the debugging features it provides.

Comment: Update: with CUDA 5.5 it is possible to debug using a single GPU (of compute capability 3.5 or higher) which also drives the display; see e.g.: http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cudacasts-episode-4-single-gpu-debugging-cuda-5-5/